# Express.js (4.13.1) and Handlebars view engine - how to setup?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

My project directory is called `travel` which has required dependencies `node_modules` and a subdir called `views`. Views subdirectory has layouts subdirectory. In the `~/travel/views/layouts` there is  `.handlebar`  templates for the views. But when I go to the browser and type in `localhost:3000/about` or just `localhost:3000` regardless of that I get `404 - not found` I tried switching the `res.render("about");` to `res.render("/views/layouts/about");` but that does not work neither. It has something to do with the paths but I'm not sure what.

```
var express=require("express");

var app=express();

// set up handlebars view engine
var handlebars=require("express3-handlebars")
    .create({defaultLayout:"main"});
app.engine("handlebars",handlebars.engine);
app.set("view engine","handlebars");

app.set("port",process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render("home");
});
app.get("/about",function(req,res){
    res.render("about");
});


// custom 404 page (middleware)
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.status(404);
    res.render("404");
});

// custom 500 page (middleware)
app.use(function(err,req,res,next){
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500);
    res.render("500");
});

app.listen(app.get("port"),function(){
    console.log("Express started on http://localhost:"+app.get("port")+";press ctrl+c to terminate,");
});
```

Comment: what happens for `res.render("./views/layouts/about")` ? Notice the dot in front.

Comment: show us your app folder structure

Comment: @sam100rav  `my project root` - `~/travel` which contains the `travel.js` as shown above,and 2 folders - `node_modules` folder and `views` folder. And the `views` folder contains `layouts` folder, which contains the `.handlebar` templates for `/about` and `/`. So the templates for views is in the `~/travel/views/layouts` also I set up my working directory to `~/travel`

Comment: @hassansin it's the same. Does not work

Comment: I tried to move the `.handlebar` templates from `~/travel/views/layouts` to `~/travel` still doesnt work O_o

Comment: why you are getting 404 instead of 500?

Comment: Now as everything should work I'm getting `Error: ENOENT, open 'c:\Users\Raimondas\travel\views\layouts\main.handlebars'
   at Error (native)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a subdirectory called `views` within the same directory as your Express app script, you need to set the Express [`views` app setting](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.settings.table) like:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

By default, the path is relative to the *current working directory*.

Additionally, you may wish to update your `express3-handlebars` module to be `express-handlebars` instead, as the latter is the newer of the two and is recommended by the current maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this by overriding the default layout

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
res.render('home', {layout: false}); });
```